# MySQL Unrelated columns or join tables using row number

Tags: mysql

I have these tables

tbl_village

```
id | village_no 
1 | V1
2 | V2
3 | V3
```

tbl_house

```
id | house_no |village_id 
1 | H1 | 1
2 | H2 | 1
3 | H3 | 2
```

tbl_street

```
id | street_no | village_id 
1 | S1 | 1 
2 | S2 | 1 
3 | S3 | 1
```

The tbl_house and tbl_street have no relationship.

Now I want to create a script that will result to this:

```
Village No | House Nos | Streets
V1 | H1 | S1
V1 | H2 | S2 
V1 | __ | S3 
V2 | H3 | __
V3 | __ | __
```

I tried this code:

```
SELECT v.village_no, h.house_no, s.street_no
FROM tbl_village v LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_house h ON (v.id=h.village_id) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_street s ON (v.id=s.village_id)
GROUP BY v.village_no, h.house_no, s.street_no
```

Script Result:

```
Village No | House Nos | Streets
V1 | H1 | S1
V1 | H2 | S1
V1 | H1 | S2
V1 | H2 | S2
V1 | H1 | S3
V1 | H2 | S3
V2 | H3 | __
V3 | __ | __
```

and it does not give the result I want because the tbl_house and tbl_street is not related to each other.

Comment: And what is your issue? What have you already tried?

Comment: @fifonik I have tried the left join but it does not give the result I want because the tbl_house and tbl_street tables have no relationship

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick MySQL version 8.0.13

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Please explain why the pairs `H1, S1` and `H2, S2` must be selected whereas pairs `H1, S2` and `H2, S1` - must not? Why not backward, for example? Why `S3` is related to `house = NULL`?

Comment: @Akina they are just in row order by village. See my answer...

Comment: *they are just in row order by village* Unclear. Add this "row order" as virtual column, for example. Do not forget - there is no records order in a table, physical order is a fake, the table is an unordered heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8 you can implement this by using `ROW_NUMBER()` to join the house and street values for each village in a simulated `FULL JOIN` (by using a `UNION` of a `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join), and then `LEFT JOIN` that to the village table to get houses and streets for each village:

```
WITH houses AS (
  SELECT house_no, village_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY village_id ORDER BY house_no) AS rn
  FROM tbl_house
),
streets AS (
  SELECT street_no, village_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY village_id ORDER BY street_no) AS rn
  FROM tbl_street
),
sh AS (
  SELECT h.village_id, h.house_no, s.street_no, h.rn
  FROM houses h 
  LEFT JOIN streets s ON s.village_id = h.village_id AND s.rn = h.rn
  UNION
  SELECT s.village_id, h.house_no, s.street_no, s.rn
  FROM houses h 
  RIGHT JOIN streets s ON s.village_id = h.village_id AND s.rn = h.rn
)
SELECT v.village_no, sh.house_no, sh.street_no
FROM tbl_village v
LEFT JOIN sh ON sh.village_id = v.id
ORDER BY v.id, sh.rn
```

Output:

```
village_no  house_no    street_no
V1          H1          S1
V1          H2          S2
V1                      S3
V2          H3  
V3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1b56908efd701065901c13afdc0573b)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `left join` to get the columns

```php
select tbl_village.village_no, tbl_house.house_no, tbl_street.street_no
from tbl_village
left join tbl_house on tbl_house.village_id = tbl_village.id
left join tbl_street on tbl_street.village_id = tbl_village.id
group by tbl_village.village_no, tbl_house.house_no
```

Comment: This is my initial code but it does not give the result I want because the tbl_house and tbl_street have no relationship.

Comment: @code4funN4treasure why `v1 h2 s2`, not `v1 h2 s1`?